# Localization of HTML documents?

Tags: html, xml, localization, dtd

XML documents can be localized by referring to an external DTD document that contains the translations. For example in Mozilla XULRunner it looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet href="chrome://global/skin/" type="text/css"?>
<!DOCTYPE window SYSTEM "chrome://configpanel/locale/configpanel.dtd">
<window title="&CONFIG_PANEL;">
  <label value="&WELCOME_TEXT;"/>
</window>
```

I've tried it in a HTML document but it didn't seem to work. Is this supposed to work for HTML documents? Or is there a similar mechanism that can be used here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This isn't supposed to work in HTML. I suggest you just do the localisation on the server-side.

Comment: Strictly speaking, this i *supposed* to work in HTML, it just doesn't, on account of being insane.

Comment: Strictly speaking, it isn't. Check the HTML5 specification.

Comment: Who said anything about HTML5? It's fairly obvious that for anything to do with DTDs, it's *not* HTML5, but HTML4.01 or XHTML.

Comment: Regardless of the DTD, pages sent as text/html are treated as defined in HTML5. Claiming anything else isn't productive.

Answer (score 1):

I'm going to go right ahead and say that that isn't really a good way of localizing XML, and it probably won't work for HTML in most browsers.

The canonical way of localizing XML documents is using the `xml:lang` attribute.